# F# Implementing Interface, Multiple Parameters, getting error this override takes a different number of

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, f#, .net-3.5, .net-4.0

I have defined the following interface in F#

```
[<ServiceContract>]
type ICarRentalService =
    [<OperationContract>]
    abstract member CalculatePrice: pickupDate:DateTime -> returnDate:DateTime -> pickupLocation:string -> vehiclePreference:string -> float
```

then I tried to implement it like this:

```
type CarRentalService() =
    interface ICarRentalService with
        override this.CalculatePrice(pickupDate:DateTime, returnDate:DateTime, pickupLocation:string, vehiclePreference:string) =
            5.5
```

When compiling I get the following compile error:

```
This override takes a different number of arguments to the corresponding abstract member
```

I'm now looking at the thing and fiddling around for an hour, what do I do wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Method in your interface is declared in curried form and your implementation is tupled:
if briefly: method in interface is function that accepts one argument and returns another function with remaining arguments. In opposite implementation accepts all arguments in one piece (packed in tuple)

```
open System
type ICarRentalService =
    abstract member CalculatePrice: pickupDate:DateTime -> returnDate:DateTime -> pickupLocation:string -> vehiclePreference:string -> float

let x : ICarRentalService = failwith "not implemented"
let a = x.CalculatePrice // DateTime -> DateTime -> string -> string -> float
let y = a (DateTime.Now) // DateTime -> string -> string -> float (first argument is bound)
```

To fix the code you need either to make implementation curried or declaration - tupled. Curried version will not work with WCF so consider using tupled version

```
type ICarRentalService =
    abstract member CalculatePrice: pickupDate:DateTime * returnDate:DateTime * pickupLocation:string * vehiclePreference:string -> float

type CarRentalService() =
    interface ICarRentalService with
        override this.CalculatePrice(pickupDate:DateTime, returnDate:DateTime, pickupLocation:string, vehiclePreference:string) =
            5.5
```